# Let $R_i$ be a family of integrally closed domains contained in a bigger domain. Then is $\cap_i R_i$ integrally closed?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R_i$ be a family of integrally closed domains contained in a bigger domain. Then is $\cap_i R_i$ integrally closed ?

Comment: Yes, it is. What you tried in order to show this?

Comment: I was considering the minimal monic polynomial and was trying to show somehow the coefficients will be in $\cap_i$ $R_i$

Comment: @SoumikGhosh Why so instead of taking an element $x$ in the field of fractions of $\cap_iR_i$ which is integral over $\cap_iR_i$? Then $x$ belongs to the field of fractions of $R_i$ and is integral over $R_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: Ohh I got up to this ... I see I misread the definition of integrally closed.. My mistake..